# C# 6.0 Features Not Working with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, c#-6.0

I am testing Visual Studio 2015 with C# 6.0 but the language features are not working. In an MVC web application, the following code does compile:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Profile?.TypeName))
{
    // More logic here...
}
```

However, when I run the application via Debug and IIS Express, I get the following error:

> CS1525: Invalid expression term '.'

How do I enable these features?

Comment: This sounds like it's MVC-specific (or at least ASP.NET-specific) so I've added a tag - because Visual Studio itself clearly knows about C# 6... you should look at wherever you configure MVC in terms of the version of .NET it's targeting... it's possible that there's something there which will let you specify the compiler to use.

Comment: Maybe you need to add a `compiler` element for the roslyn codeprovider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9x69bzw(v=vs.110).aspx in the web.config?

Comment: Is this code that's in an aspx page or Razor page?  or code that's in a .cs file?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch It's in a Razor page.

Comment: Are you using MVC5 or MVC6?

Comment: I'm using MVC5. Looks like I need to get the project ported to MVC6...

Comment: Yeah, MVC5 isn't Roslyn compatible

Comment: I had this issue with one single Razor view only. This was apparently caused by the fact that one project was referencing `MVC 5.2.6` via NuGet and the other was a **manual reference** added to `MVC 5.2.3` This conflict didn't show up on the NuGet Manage Solution > Consolidate tab because it was a **manual reference**. Once I updated it to be `MVC 5.2.6` this error went away.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

This works in MVC 5 (tested 5.2.3), you just need to add the roslyn code dom Nuget package

### CodeDOM Providers for .NET Compiler...

> Replacement CodeDOM providers that use the new .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn") compiler as a service APIs. This provides support for new language features in systems using CodeDOM (e.g. ASP.NET runtime compilation) as well as improving the compilation performance of these systems.

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/

Comment: This should be submitted as an answer, because it fixes the problem rather than having to upgrade to a beta version of MVC.

Comment: @Deef you are incorrect. The *Microsoft.Net.Compilers* is related to Msbuild. the *CodeDOM Providers* is related to ASP.NET and other api's that compile at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I misread/misinterpretted because they sometimes repalces packages with new names and just add them as dependencies.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning to restart Visual Studio. It kept complaining after I installed the package, but a restart made it go away :)

Comment: When I run that I get a message saying "Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform'"  How do I get around this?

Comment: @Rono, Make sure your package source is `nuget.org`. As you can see from the link, it is the correct name, and the package exists.

Comment: Had to delete all the dlls in the bin folder first before it would build

Comment: This answer also works for VS2017 RC4. In addition if you are using ReSharper you may have to restart VS to make the red squiggly lines go away. I'm using VS2017 RC4 with R# 2016.3.2.

Comment: This answer worked for me: VS2017 v15.7.3. I got the error message "Error CS8026 Feature 'interpolated strings' is not available in C# 5. Please use language version 6 or greater." when using c# > v5 featrues in razor views in a asp.net mvc 4.6.1 project. See also (http://dave.ninja/c-6/using-c-6-0-features-in-asp-net-mvc-razor/ and https://dusted.codes/using-csharp-6-features-in-aspdotnet-mvc-5-razor-views)

Answer (score 17):

Well, I have MVC5 and recently installed VS 2015.

I've installed CodeDOM providers package, but it didn't help... 
But after that I realized, that package supports framework 4.5 only, while I have target framework set to 4.6 during tests - it works with 4.5 though...

So pay attention also to target framework. If you have 4.5 - just install package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform. But if you have 4.5.1-4.6 as a target, you will have to change in web.config section

```
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701">
          <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0"/>
      </compiler>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

For **C#**, just change **type** to:

```
type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
```

Comment: This certainly helped me getting `C# 6` to work with `ASP.NET 4.6`, but it might have been better to post the code with the correct `type` already there...

Comment: Thanks, this had been working when I went home on a Tuesday and then didn't work when I came back on the Thursday. Somehow, this section of the config had gone AWOL, because I remember seeing it when I was getting it to work originally!

Answer (score 16):

I was having this same problem in Visual Studio 2015.  Another answer here alluded to the solution I used, but they incorrectly specified the fix and never gave clarification.

On the the Visual Studio menu, select **Project** and you should see the sub-item **Enable C#6 / VB 14** if you are having this problem.  Select this menu sub-item.  It will download the correct packages from Nuget and install them.  After this, restart Visual Studio and reload your solution.

I cannot verify if this will also fix the **Project Properties > Build > Advanced > Language Version** selection to **C# 6**, so you might want to check this as well after enabling C# 6 from the menu.

Comment: This sub-item is not in my Project menu. I have Unity 5.5.2 that opened up my VS 2015 Community to create some scripts. Upon adding a default to a property a compiler error showed by the red unline, stating I needed c# 6 as C# v.4 was currently loaded. Anytime I try to select properties of the project the screen just flashes but no page comes up.

Answer (score 15):

Check your project properties, go to build, advanced and see if C# 6.0 if you don't have it as default.

Currently there's perfect support for MVC5 and C# 6.0 and works amazingly well!

Comment: "Feature 'null propagating operator' is not available in C# 5. Please use language version 6 or greater." 

didn't know about the Advanced setting but doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: How do you change the default version to 6 so that I don't have to set it on each project?

Comment: define "some". this does not work in vs 2015 update 3.

Comment: When I got to project properties, I do not get a build menu.     

If I go to "Property Pages" I get a build menu, but I do not have an "advanced" button on the build screen.    

Translation, "This does not work" (for me)

Comment: My VS version is Community 2015 Update 3 (14.0.25431.01)

Comment: @MalcolmAnderson it worked for me. Do you have a web site or web application project? I have a web application project. I get the "full-screen" project properties (by right clicking project file and clicking Properties, or by double clicking Properties node in the project itself), then click the Build tab, then click the button "Advanced..." which gives me the C# language selector. Mine was set to 'auto', but I have since changed it.

Comment: These options are not available in a Web Site. So it doesn't work for people who aren't using a Web Application. Before someone says "just change to an Application", some of us have legacy applications to support, and aren't allowed to make changes unless requested.

Answer (score 12):

Including following the advice of installing the latest `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` I also had to set my **root** `Web.config` `system.codedom` to this to finally get all of the errors in `Visual Studio 2015` to go away:

```
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

Now restart `Visual Studio` and that should do it.

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio 2015 will also show an `Enable C#6 / VB 14` in the Project menu with an ASP.NET web site / web application selected.

This will de facto install `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` and `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` packages into your project and add appropriate tags into web.config file.

[image: visual studio 2015 - enable cs6 snipp]

Comment: what website tab? if you mean properties/web there is no such feature there.

Comment: I Visual Studio, when you select some WebSite project, the Website tab appears next to View tab. There you may find this feature.

Comment: I've downvoted for now, please edit to clarify what exactly you mean, e.g. by adding a screenshot.

Comment: I'm trying to fix the issue with a Website, and that menu item is not available for me. Note that other non-Web projects in the same solution have no problem using VB 14 features. They all target .NET 4.7, and I installed the CodeDom compiler.

Answer (score -1):

```
<compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:7 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
<compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:15 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
```