# Where to configure Razor page language version to C# 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, razor

Recently I've tried to use some C# 6 new feature (interpolated strings) in my ASP.NET MVC (5) .cshtml view, but when running got an error message complaining about the `$`. It is clear the compiler in C# 5 compatibility mode, or worst it *is* a C# 5 compiler.

When in editor a popup warning warns me (I do not know it is VS or ReSharper) `Feature 'Interpolated strings' is not available in C# 5. Please use language version 6 or greater.`

The project itself was set to C# 6, and I can use C# 6 features in my build time compiled code like controllers etc.

Q: Where should I set page compiler version, *and will this C# 6 compiler available when I deploy my web app to Azure there?*

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832659/c-sharp-6-string-interpolation-in-a-razor-view

Comment: Except it has possibly incorrect answer. That's is my wording in the question about compiler version.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968963/c-sharp-6-0-features-not-working-with-visual-studio-2015/31548221#31548221. Some features won't work, but most will.

Answer (score 4):

From [String interpolation in a Razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832659/c-sharp-6-string-interpolation-in-a-razor-view):

This only works in MVC6.  Alternatively, also from a comment on this link, you'll need to add the roslyn code dom package from ASP.Net.

```
<div>
    @($"Hello {this.Model.SomeProperty}")
</div>
```

As far as Azure is concerned, please see this link. http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/08/11/update-on-net-framework-4-6-and-azure/

> With great power… The tooling, framework and Azure platform teams want
>   to ensure the powerful tools we give you to help build your dream is
>   matched by the responsibility we recognize we have to keep it running
>   in the cloud. At the time of the Visual Studio and Azure SDK 2.7
>   releases, Framework 4.6 wasn’t supported broadly throughout Azure.
>   This is due in large part to the fact that just as many teams (or
>   more) are responsible for the ongoing development and stability of the
>   Azure platform.
>
> For now, we have an update on the availability of .NET Framework 4.6
>   for Azure App Service and an article demonstrating how to get .NET
>   Framework 4.6 working in your Cloud Service roles.
>
> **Azure IaaS** 
>   For customers using Azure’s Infrastructure as a Service
>   (IaaS) services, installation of .NET Framework 4.6 is manual. To
>   install .NET Framework 4.6 on an Azure IaaS virtual machine, the
>   process is as simple as logging into the virtual machine using Remote
>   Desktop. Once on the machine, the .NET Framework 4.6 installer can be
>   downloaded and installed directly onto the virtual machine. Customers
>   using Azure Automation could also choose to automate the installation
>   onto Azure virtual machines using PowerShell.
>
> **Azure App Service**
>   Update The Azure App Service team is nearing the end
>   of the testing phase for .NET Framework 4.6 and planning the
>   deployment to the environments. Currently, the plan is to roll out the
>   updates to Azure App Service during August 2015.
>
> **Azure Cloud Services** 
>   Saurabh Bhatia authored an article in the Azure
>   documentation center outlining how to install the .NET Framework in a
>   Cloud Service Role. The content has been recently updated to include
>   commentary specific to .NET Framework 4.6. You can find the updated
>   article here on the Azure documentation center.

Comment: Thanks. Read the link you referenced. Although I understand that Razor's intuitive switch between markup and C# does not work seamlessly with the  $, I think the compiler version has nothing to do with this, that's why my wording in my question. Once Razor recognizes it's C# it goes to the generated C# class. Then it's entirely up the the configured compiler it understands or gives an error.

Comment: My main concern is IIS and Azure.

Comment: Updated answer with link on .Net 4.6 and Azure

Answer (score 3):

For me installing the `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` NuGet package solved the problem.