# CS1525: Invalid expression term '.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, runtime-error

I'm facing a weird problem for 5 days. Tried many thing starting of Googling and with no luck.

I think it's about my pc configuration but I couldn't found where it could be what's fixing.

The error message is:
`CS1525: Invalid expression term '.'`

Source:

at line 17.

```html
Line 15:     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
Line 16:     <title><%=notifies.Count > 0 ? "("+notifies.Count+")" : "" %>
> Line 17:         <%:Core.memberInfo?.Username %>[<%:Core.memberInfo?.ID %>] /
Line 18:         <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="titleAddons"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
Line 19:         :: <%:Core.siteOptions.SiteTitle %></title>
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2017. Project coding by .net 4.7.2. There is no build errors.

How can it be fixed?

Thank you for now..

Comment: I guess the compiler version is too low. Will this error still be reported after deleting the question mark？

Comment: @shingo I faced some more errors about compiler. So I used max version of it. This didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @rene Why can't I use null coalesce? It was work as a charm for a while ago. I don't know what did I change within my pc to face that. And, this is a huge project which has about 450k rows.

Comment: @rene no! It's not the same with that link which you shared since I'm using c# 7.3.

Comment: @shingo The compiler is "Microsoft.Net.Compilers.4.2.0".

Comment: does using `<%=` instead of `<%:` resolve the issue? What does the compilation element in your web.config says?

Comment: @rene no. `<%=` not solved the issue. There is no line for compilation in web.config according to solve some other issues.

Comment: Maybe your machine config is off, try adding this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40171685 to your web.config to have more fine grained control.

Comment: @rene, Sorry! I misunderstood your previous question. The compilation line is `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8">`

Comment: Would it work without the `? `, so just `Core.memberInfo.Username`? Of course it will then crash on null

Comment: Do you need (update) this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform ?

Comment: Yes, @HansKeﬆing. It's working without `?`. But also it was working with it for a while ago. And, I can't remove those question marks since there are too many of them in my project.

Comment: Since I was using "Microsoft.Net.Compilers.4.2.0", there is no need to use "DotNetCompilerPlatform", as I know. @HansKeﬆing

Comment: About that ? was not a suggestion to remove it, but a check about the compiler version. The version you are using is apparently too old to understand the null-conditional operator

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, please direct me to change compiler from "Microsoft.Net.Compilers.4.2.0" to "DotNetCompilerPlatform". NuGet is jamming when install "DotNetCompilerPlatform" to the project. When I install it, I have errors about 12k. For example "Element 'page' is not a known element" vs. While googling, I found the solution by removing compilers declarations. So, I stucked at there.

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012051/where-to-configure-razor-page-language-version-to-c-sharp-6

Comment: Thank you @HansKeﬆing. I solved my problem with your previous recognizing.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all to your efforts.

I removed from `"Microsoft.Net.Compilers.4.2.0"` to `"Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.4.1.0"`.

I made sure there is no rows in web.config for those two and there is no row for `Microsoft.Net.Compiler.4.2.0` because of previous experiments.

This is strange because I tried it before with no luck. But, after some restarting and cleaning some folders could be worked.