# Using C# 6 String interpolation in Razor the Correct Way

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, c#-6.0

**Example**:

```
 <button data-value="$'{@item.CustomerID}_{@item.CustomerType}'"></button>
```

**Result**:

```
$'{34645}_{71}'
```

**Expected**:

```
34645_71
```

**Update**:
Had to Enable C#6 and install the appropriate package for @smdrager's last two techniques to work. In VS2015>>Click Project Menu>>Click Enable 6#

Comment: Are you dead-set on using string interpolation or just looking for the best way to get that output?

Comment: @DStanley, dead-set if possible.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832659/string-interpolation-in-a-razor-view to enable C# 6 in Razor views

Comment: I was just about to do that because VS started highlighting the line with red "feature interpolated strings is not available in c# 5"

Comment: @DavidL, please take a quick look at smdrager answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the example you provided, string interpolation is not necessary. Using standard razor syntax, you can get the result you want with:

```
<button data-value="@(item.CustomerID)_@item.CustomerType"></button>
```

Which will produce`<button data-value="34567_123"></button>`

The equivallent with interpolation would be:

```
@Html.Raw($"<button data-value='{item.CustomerID}_{item.CustomerType}'></button>")
```

But you lose out on HTML encoded to prevent script injection (though this seems unlikely with the data types you are dealing with).

**Edit:**

If you want to get completely wacky, you can mix both.

```
<button data-value="@($"{item.CustomerID}_{item.CustomerType}")"></button>
```

But that is more verbose and difficult to read.

Comment: Just tried the first technique, @item.CustomerID_ does not work. CustomerID would not be recognized because of the underscore.

Comment: @DStanley, right and verified..thx! I think this needs to be edited in the answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. I corrected the answer. Sometimes you need to use parentheses to clear up confusion for the razor parser.