# Razor Engine String Interpolation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

When compiling a Razor View in my unit test project, I encounter this string interpolation error:

> Unexpected character '$'

I have looked at this thread [String interpolation in a Razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832659/string-interpolation-in-a-razor-view) and followed the steps in the answers to install the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/ Nuget package and modify my app.config file accordingly but I am still getting the error.

My language version is set to 'automatically selected based on framework version' and is greyed out and I am unable to change, and the project is using MVC 5.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? The Stack Overflow question I linked to earlier is over 5 years old so I wonder if there's some sort of update?

Comment: Could you please check your framework version?

Comment: @RomanKlimenko 4.7.2

Comment: Probably, this article will help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version I have just tried `dotnet new mvc ; dotnet run` and I can use string interpolation without any additional configuration.

Comment: Already answered. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832659/string-interpolation-in-a-razor-view)

Comment: @JanLacina I have addressed that answer in my comment and explained I have tried that approach :)