# How to make razor view engine to use C# 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Currently my razor view engine throws and error saying:

> Please use language version 6 or higher.

That may just be resharper giving me a pointer. But how do I make razor use C# 6.0. Rest of my solution in the cs files I can use all the new version 7 features.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# 6.0 Features Not Working with Visual Studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968963/c-sharp-6-0-features-not-working-with-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: no - that solution did not fix this problem.

Answer (score 31):

I believe this is due to a bug in the templates for `web.config` when the project is upgraded to a newer version of the .net framework.

I was able to fix this by going in to `web.config`, finding the `system.codedom` node, and changing the content to look like this:

```
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers>
```

Comment: Microsoft.Net.Compilers and
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform must be installed in order to work

Comment: (Re-)Installing the above two packages will add this section to the .config file.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Alen, and I found that just installing Nuget pkg for Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform is enough since Microsoft.Net.Compilers is a dependency.

Comment: [DotNetCompilerPlatform  v3.6.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/3.6.0) no longer has a dependency on `Microsoft.Net.Compilers`

Answer (score 20):

If you are running this from a `4.5.1` project, upgrading to `4.5.2` might fix it.

Otherwise, it is recommended to install this NuGet package to provide the new functionalities: `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`

So doing something like this:

```
<p>@Model.Person?.Name</p>
```

Might work. If it doesn't, try being explicit like this:

```
<p>@(Model.Person?.Name)</p>
```

Answer (score 12):

Other answers are quite good, but I found a good and short article that definitively clarify the steps for this issue: https://cpratt.co/using-csharp-6-or-7-with-mvc-5/

In short:

1. In the Package Manager Console install `Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`
2. checka/alters you Web.config with the following lines at the end:

```
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp"
      extension=".cs"
      type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
      warningLevel="4"
      compilerOptions="/langversion:7 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
    <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript"
      extension=".vb"
      type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
      warningLevel="4"
      compilerOptions="/langversion:15 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

Answer (score 4):

The best step-by-step instructions I could find for enable C# 6 features in RazorEngine templates is here: https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/363#issuecomment-273106183

What's not mentioned in there is to make sure when adding the compilers section to your app.config, that the version number matches the version from the package you are installing.  In the comment it was version 1.0.3, but the package I installed had 1.0.4 instead, so it needed to look like this:

```
<system.codedom>
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
</compilers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder in project's solutions with this name

```
Directory.Build.props
```

Then add this dependency

```
<Project>
 <PropertyGroup>
  <LangVersion>6.0</LangVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```