# Using the null propagation operator in an ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2, c#-6.0

I've tried one or two combinations of using the null propagation operator in an ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 razor view but the compiler doesn't understand this syntax at all.

```
<input type="text" 
       name="Name" 
       class="form-control" 
       placeholder = "John Doe" 
       value = "@(Model?.Name)" />
```

Short of this, I will have to either use a ternary operator or wrap the whole thing in a large `if (Model == null)` statement with an else block. How do I avoid that?

Comment: Nope. It's a different question.

Comment: Maybe you can find the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968963/c-sharp-6-0-features-not-working-with-visual-studio-2015

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 Which version of Razor are you using? Also, what version of the .NET framework are you targeting?

Comment: Why not just use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", new placeholder ="John Doe")`?