# VS 2015 will not build my project as C# 6.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, c#-6.0

Per tags this is an ASP MVC project in Visual Studio 2015. Code in Razor:

```
@if (Model.AdditionalContacts?.Count > 0) { }
```

Error received:

> Feature 'null propagating operator' is not available in C# 5. Please use language version 6 or greater.

I'm using VS 2015. Why was this not defaulted?

Steps taken to fix:

- Open Project's `Properties`
- Click `Build`
- Click `Advanced`
- Set `Language Version` to `C# 6.0`
- Clean / Rebuild

Same error occurs. Why?

**[Edit]:** The code works fine in the CS file directly. I even switched the language back to "default" rather than C# 6.0 and it works. It only does not work in the CSHTML files. Does Razor not support this? Or perhaps this is related to IIS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# 6.0 features are not automatically available in MVC5 projects (in Razor), you have two options:

- Update to MVC 6 beta
- Install CodeDOM Providers for .NET Compiler, [see details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31548221/637783)

Comment: You should update the answer to clarify that it's the Razor *files* that can't use C# 6 features. C# 6 works just fine in the rest of an MVC 5 project. Moreover, if you find a duplicate question, vote to close the current one as duplicate. Multiple answers to identical questions just create noise, making it harder to find the correct answer.