# Does the null conditional work in a Razor view?

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages

I have in a Razor view file:

```
<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
<pre>@Model.Exception.Message</pre>
<pre>@Model.Exception.InnerException?.Message</pre>
<pre>@Model.info</pre>
```

The `InnerException?.Message` shows more than the `Message` property. It looks like the output of the `ToString()` method:

[image]

If I instead of the null conditional operator I used:

```
@if (Model.Exception.InnerException != null)
{
  <pre>@Model.Exception.InnerException.Message</pre>
}
```

then it comes out as I wanted:

[image]

Is the syntax I am using for the null conditional operator incorrect?

Comment: `@(Model.Exception.InnerException?.Message)` does this work ?

Comment: (Y)! Thanks. There was no error without the parentheses so how was the `?` interpreted?

Comment: Im guessing it just allows it to parse better, i dont really have an explanation, maybe someone can answer with one

Comment: Interesting, I would expect the string "?.Message" at the end of the stack trace in your first example, which is hidden in the screenshot.

Comment: Yes, it was "...Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)?.Message".  So it looks like it treated `?.Message` as literal text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem occurred because implicit Razor expression is used with HTML tag precedes it:

```
<pre>@Model.Exception.InnerException?.Message</pre>
```

which interpreted as this, hence the parser only reads `Model.Exception.InnerException` property:

```
<pre>@(Model.Exception.InnerException.ToString())?.Message</pre>
```

The null-conditional operator in C# 6.0 and above requires usage of explicit expression in certain Razor versions before introduction of C# 6.0 because the implicit expression parser still following previous versions of C# syntax. Since the explicit expression syntax allows flexibility to parse server-side code according to current C# version, the expression above should be written like this:

```
<pre>@(Model.Exception.InnerException?.Message)</pre>
```

**Note:**

This is an edge case which Razor misinterpreted null-conditional operator as part of literal string instead of code with implicit expression, and explicit expression helps render property content.

Reference:

[Explicit Razor expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.2#explicit-razor-expressions)

Related issue:

[The new null-conditional operator in ASP.NET MVC Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171579/the-new-null-conditional-operator-in-asp-net-mvc-razor)