# Enabling C# 6 on MVC 5 does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper, asp.net-mvc-5, c#-6.0

I know people have asked this question before and I tried their solutions but I still have problems.

### In short:

my **code compiles and I can browse the page** and everything, but **VS keep showing me the error**

> Error  CS8026  Feature 'null propagating operator' is not available in C# 5.
>   Please use language version 6 or greater.

[image]

### I went through all answers here:

[C# 6.0 Features Not Working with Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968963/c-sharp-6-0-features-not-working-with-visual-studio-2015)

### What Do I have

- VS 2015 update 3, ReSharper Ultimate 2017.1.2, MVC 5
- latest version of codedome
- This section in my webconfig

Code

```
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, Pub[1]licKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:7 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:15 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

I tried .net framework 4.6.1 and 4.6.2

[image: .net version]

Set language version to C# 6.0 on my build>advanced[image: advanced]

I don't have the enable C# 6, button probably because it is already enabled for the compiler.
 [image]

- I have Resharper installed but I've closed and reopened visual studio several times. it didn't work

Comment: Try to close VS, delete `.vs` solution folder and open it again.

Comment: @IlyaChumakov thanks for answer. didn't work :(

Comment: Is `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` package installed?

Comment: `Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`

Comment: @AshkanSirous. I am facing the same issue with VS2019. I have DotNetCompilerPlatform NuGet package but keep getting Feature 'null propagating operator' is not available in C# 4 even if I am targeting C#7.3. How did you solve this?