# How to update C# Compiler to version 6-Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: c#

I have been trying to update my C# compiler after getting the below error when trying to compile a file:

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

I downloaded Roslyn as directed (not sure if it needed to go in a particular folder with the visual studio files) but didn't get any further with it.

I also found guidance to run the below command in visual studio :

Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers

But this also generates errors when attempting, regardless of whether or not a solution is open.

I'm trying to get the compiler to update to version 6, I feel like this should be very simple but I haven't gotten anywhere with the advice I've researched. Any ideas?

Comment: Install Visual Studio Community 2017. Also make sure to update the language version in the project settings `Build` tab, click `Adavanced` button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# 6.0 Features Not Working with Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968963/c-sharp-6-0-features-not-working-with-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: It is not an error, just a notification from the old compiler to remind you that it is, you know, old.  Why you are not using the one provided by VS2015 is very unclear.  Do create a project instead of trying to jockey it from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition you should already have the C# 6 compilers since they shipped with Visual Studio 2015.

I just installed the RTM version of Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition on a clean system.  The `csc.exe` compiler it installs (under `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\` reports itself as **Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 1.0.0.50618**.  The file's modified date is 6/21/2015.

The help section on the langversion switch reports **/langversion: <string>         Specify language version mode: ISO-1, ISO-2, 3, 4, 5, 6, or Default**

> This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

The wording of this warning message suggests that you are using a version of the C# compiler shipped with the .NET Framework rather than one that was shipped with Visual Studio 2015.